# Exporting File to CSV merges up cell with spaces

Tags: php, html, csv

```html
<script>function doCSV() {
    var table = document.getElementById("player_info").innerHTML;
    var data = table.replace(/<thead>/g, '')
        .replace(/<\/thead>/g, '')
        .replace(/<tbody>/g, '')
        .replace(/<\/tbody>/g, '')
        .replace(/<tr>/g, '')
        .replace(/<\/tr>/g, '\r\n')
        .replace(/<th>/g, '')
        .replace(/<\/th>/g, ',')
        .replace(/<td>/g, '')
        .replace(/<\/td>/g, ',')
        .replace(/\t/g, '')
        .replace(/\n/g, '');
    var mylink = document.createElement('a');
    mylink.download = "fplinfo.csv";
    mylink.href = "data:application/csv," + escape(data);
    mylink.click();
}</script>
```

I have this [site](http://fplanalyze.fplnepal.com/draft/fplinfo.php)where I can fetch the data from fpl site. 
I can export the file form web in csv file, but the problem is 
if the `web name` or `Full name` have some other character text like `Mesut Özil` `Ö` , those particular rows merges up the cell if there is any spaces 
 in the table. Rest of the rows are fine. 
I have looked up the proble, but I cannot understand, whats wrong, because rest of them are working normal.

Comment: That looks like more code than strictly needed. Can you reduce the code further until no code can be removed while still running into the problem?

Comment: Sorry for the all the codes, yes I have removed all the html format and just included the csv upload button code.